# Viewing the result that a query return with "puts"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a query something like this in my controller that I am passing it as JSON to JBuilder,etc.... But JBuilder shows nothing! it just shows { }

```
@students =  Students.top_students.joins(:program).where("programs.organization_id = ?", params[:id]).limit(10)
```

So before it gets to there I just wanted to make sure it is getting the correct data, its joins are correct, etc.. 
So can I do that?

If I just say `puts @students` it will print something like, I want to see what is inside each of them.

```
#<Student:0x007fd33ebe57a8>
#<Student:0x007fd33ebe4d08>
#<Student:0x007fd33ebe3ea8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a `to_s` method on `Student` and your `puts` output will be more useful. I'd recommend using `inspect`:

```
def to_s
  inspect
end
```

Alternatively, you could iterate through `@students` and do more output:

```
@students.each do |student|
  puts "Id: #{student.id}"
  puts "Name: #{student.name}"
  ...
end
```

Or if you want to keep it simple, a quick `collect` will do the trick:

```
puts @students.collect(&:inspect)
```

Comment: nice. I didn't know of that inspect method.  I heard of something like flat_map or something?  Have you worked with that too?

Comment: I haven't before, but there is some documentation here: http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map